# Issue with the Factur-X Python library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.8 and the library from Alexis de Lattre : https://github.com/akretion/factur-x.

As you can read on his repo, it is used to generate Factur-X invoices from a regular PDF invoice and a Factur-X compliant XML file.

I used the command line tools very kindly provided :

- facturx-pdfextractxml.py [input pdf_file_name] [output facturx_xml_file_name]
- facturx-pdfgen.py [input pdf_file_name] [input facturx_xml_file_name] [output facturx-compliant_pdf_file_name]

successfully with a dummy example from my internal company (first attachment) :

```
2020-09-15 17:06:11,867 [INFO] A valid XML file factur-x.xml has been found in the PDF file
FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions. Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead. [facturx.py:92]
2020-09-15 17:06:11,868 [INFO] Factur-X flavor is factur-x (autodetected)
2020-09-15 17:06:11,868 [INFO] Factur-X level is basic (autodetected)
2020-09-15 17:06:11,889 [INFO] Factur-X XML file successfully validated against XSD
2020-09-15 17:06:11,890 [INFO] Returning an XML file factur-x.xml
2020-09-15 17:06:11,891 [INFO] File Facture_DOM_BASIC_5_facturx.xml generated
```

But this input example seems to be already facturx compliant from start, an example output in fact ... So I used my own PDF invoice made online (for ex. in https://app.invoicesimple.com/, 2nd attachment), or made with Word+export. This time, when using the same command line tools, I have a Catalog related error :

```
2020-09-15 17:05:36,992 [INFO] No Names entry in Catalog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facturx-pdfextractxml.py", line 95, in <module>
    main(options, arguments)
  File "facturx-pdfextractxml.py", line 80, in main
    logger.warn('File %s has not been created', out_xml_filename)
  File "C:\Users\Selim SEDIKKI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1449, in warn
    warnings.warn("The 'warn' method is deprecated, "
  File "C:\Users\Selim SEDIKKI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\warnings.py", line 109, in _showwarnmsg
    sw(msg.message, msg.category, msg.filename, msg.lineno,
  File "C:\Users\Selim SEDIKKI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyPDF4\pdf.py", line 1133, in _showwarning
    file.write(formatWarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))
  File "C:\Users\Selim SEDIKKI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyPDF4\utils.py", line 69, in formatWarning
    file = filename.replace("/", "\\").rsplit("\\", 1)[1] # find the file name
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I searched inside the python scripts for insights (main scripts and facturx.py module), and on the web, but I'm a bit stuck .. And I have a quite short deadline so I can't loose one more afternoon on my own ;)

Another subsidiary question whould be about the script facturx-pdfgen.py [input pdf_file_name] [input facturx_xml_file_name] [output facturx-compliant_pdf_file_name]. Since we generate facturx_xml_file with facturx-pdfextractxml.py, and since this xml must contain all information in the pdf, why do we need the original pdf file again with facturx-pdfgen.py ? And not start with the xml only input to produce the final Factur-X compliant PDF file ?

Thank you to anyone having a better understanding than mine ;)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find a way to include the 2 attachments. Hope the repo and command line output will be a good start to analyse. If you want the 2 invoice PDF files I used, please ask me ;) I'm just not used to posting that much (I usually find my answers on existing questions)

Comment: NB : the 2 pieces of command line output come from the execution of facturx-pdfextractxml.py

Comment: NB2 : "But this input example seems to be already facturx compliant from start, an example output in fact" => so I'm producing the exact same pdf file as my input. I need to start from a regular PDF file to demontrate the actual work of the library ;) And sorry for having too many NB. Hope that's clear enough!

Comment: NB3 : my host is a Win10 machin!! That's my last promise.

Answer (score 0):

I realized facturx-pdfextractxml.py was actually extracting preexisting xml attached in the input pdf. So we do have to parse the information contained inside the pdf and create an Factur-X compliant XML file (with all required info and proper structure), outside the futurx biblio.

I found another biblio, pdfminer, to parse the pdf, which actually can producde xml format.

Now the question is : once I have map the 2 xml (input from pdfminer, output to Factur-X compliant file), will it be robust to new invoice pdf ? In other word, are invoice pdf structure regular enough ?

I guess I will have to try. If you already some insights please share ;)